# Need a Tab system with box-shadow and round cornder everywhere :--/

Tags: css, round-corner

Here is the spec that I need :
Take special look at shadows and round corners. And that div content has also shadows and round corner.

[TAB 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vofXQ.png)

[TAB 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt5oH.png)

[TAB 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWD9O.png)

[BOTTOM OF THE CONTENT DIV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX21T.png)

I don't manager to setup box-shaddow and round corner correctly.

Here is what I did : [tab coded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AObna.gif), with the following code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <title>test box shadow</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 50px;
            background-color: #f3f4f6;
        }
        
      
/*------------------ */
#version4 .tab-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    
    border-radius:  0.75rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

#version4 .tabs {
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    border-top-left-radius:  0.75rem;
    border-top-right-radius:  0.75rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#version4 .tab {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top-left-radius:  0.75rem;
    border-top-right-radius:  0.75rem;
    background-color: white;
    /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #00000029;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 100%;
}


#version4 .tab span {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    
}

#version4 .tab::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

#version4 .tab:last-child {
    border-right: none;
    border-top-right-radius:  0.75rem;
}

#version4 .tab.active {
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}

#version4 .tab.active span {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}


#version4 .tab.active::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: white;
}
#version4 .tab-divider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#version4 .divider-container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    border-top-left-radius:  0.75rem;
    border-top-right-radius:  0.75rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0.375rem #00000029;
}

#version4 .divider-container[first] {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
#version4 .divider-container[last] {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

#version4 .divider-container .tab-divider:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#version4 .divider-container .tab-divider.active:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}

#version4 .divider-container .tab-divider:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#version4 .divider-container .tab-divider.active:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

#version4 .tab-divider.active {
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
}

#version4 .tab-content {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    /* border-top: 1px solid #ccc; */
    background-color: white;
}

#version4 .content {
    flex: 1;
}
#version4 .firstCorner {
    border-top-left-radius:  0.75rem;
}
#version4 .lastCorner {
    border-top-right-radius:  0.75rem;
}
#version4 .noCorner {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
  


  

    <section id="version4">
        <div class="tab-container">
           
            <div class="tabs">
                <div class="tab" onclick="changeTab('version4', 0)">
                    <span>Onglet 1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="tab" onclick="changeTab('version4', 1)">
                    <span>Onglet 2</span>
                </div>
                <div class="tab" onclick="changeTab('version4', 2)">
                    <span>Onglet 3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divider-container dividers">
                <div class="tab-divider"></div>
                <div class="tab-divider"></div>
                <div class="tab-divider"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="tab-content" id="tabContent0">Contenu de l'onglet 1</div>
                <div class="tab-content" id="tabContent1">Contenu de l'onglet 2</div>
                <div class="tab-content" id="tabContent2">Contenu de l'onglet 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <script>
        function changeTab(sectionId, tabIndex) {
            const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll(`#${sectionId} .tab-content`);
            const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(`#${sectionId} .tab`);
            const dividers = document.querySelectorAll(`#${sectionId} .tab-divider`);

            tabContents.forEach((content) => {
                content.style.display = 'none';
            });

            tabs.forEach((tab) => {
                tab.classList.remove('active');
            });
            dividers.forEach((tab) => {
                tab.classList.remove('active');
            });

            tabContents[tabIndex].style.display = 'block';
            tabs[tabIndex].classList.add('active');
            dividers[tabIndex].classList.add('active');


            const dividersContainer = document.querySelector(`#${sectionId} .divider-container`);
             if (tabIndex === 0) {
                dividersContainer.setAttribute('first', true);
                dividersContainer.removeAttribute('last');                
            } else if (tabIndex === 2) {
                dividersContainer.removeAttribute('fist');                
                dividersContainer.setAttribute('last', true);
            } else {
                dividersContainer.removeAttribute('first');
                dividersContainer.removeAttribute('last');                
            }

        }
        changeTab('version4', 0);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

=> Please advise how to add shadows and round corner correctly.